# Function not defined in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find the value of totalDistance, but when I type it at the bottom after 
returning the function: print(totalDistance) I get function is not define. Here is the 
entire piece I am working on. And what i am trying to get is the value totalDistance 
because I have to use it to represent the actual number value. Another question is how can I function ordinal so that it shows the "st" "nd" "rd" and "th" were I have str(s1). I am new to this and is hw so nothing fancy if you all may, basic.

```
i = 1
while i == 1:
    s1 = int(input("Starting street: "))
    while s1 % 2 == 0:
            print("Street must be a positive odd number between 1 and 99!")
            s1 = int(input("Starting street: "))
            if s1 <= 0:
                print("Street must be a positive odd number between 1 and 99!")
                s1 = int(input("Starting street: "))
            if s1 > 99:
                print("Street must be a positive odd number between 1 and 99!")
                s1 = int(input("Starting street: "))

    a1 = int(input("Starting avenue: "))
    while a1 % 2 != 0:
            print("Avenue must be a positive even number between 2 and 98!")
            a1 = int(input("Starting avenue: "))
            if a1 <= 1:
                print("Avenue must be a positive even number between 2 and 98!")
                a1 = int(input("Starting avenue: "))
            if a1 > 98:
                print("Avenue must be a positive even number between 2 and 98!")
                a1 = int(input("Starting avenue: "))

    s2 = int(input("Ending street: "))
    while s2 % 2 == 0:
            print("Street must be a positive odd number between 1 and 99!")
            s2 = int(input("Ending street: "))
            if s2 <= 0:
                print("Street must be a positive odd number between 1 and 99!")
                s2 = int(input("Starting street: "))
            if s2 > 99:
                print("Street must be a positive odd number between 1 and 99!")
                s2 = int(input("Starting street: "))

    a2 = int(input("Ending avenue: "))
    while a2 % 2 != 0:
            print("Avenue must be a positive even number between 2 and 98!")
            a2 = int(input("Ending avenue: "))
            if a2 <= 1:
                print("Avenue must be a positive even number between 2 and 98!")
                a2 = int(input("Starting avenue: "))
            if a2 > 98:
                print("Avenue must be a positive even number between 2 and 98!")
                a2 = int(input("Starting avenue: ")) 
    i = i + 1

def getDistance(s1, a1, s2, a2):
    streets = (s2 - s1)/2 * 1000
    if streets <= -1:
        import math
        streets = math.fabs(streets)

    avenues = (a2 - a1)/2 * 1000
    if avenues <= -1:
        import math
        avenues = math.fabs(avenues)

        totalDistance = streets + avenues

    return getDistance(s1, a1, s2, a2)

def ordinal(n):
    if n % 100/10 != 1:
        if n % 10 == 1:
            print(str(n) + "st")
        elif n % 10 == 2:
            print(str(n) + "nd")
        elif n % 10 == 3:
            print(str(n) + "rd")
        else:
            print(str(n) + "th")
    return ordinal       

def getDirections(s1, a1, s2, a2):
    print("Directions from " + str(s1) + " and " + str(a1) + " to " + str(s2) + " and " + str(a2))
    print("Total distance traveled :" + "ft")

getDirections(s1, a1, s2, a2)
```

Comment: When I run your code, I get a `NameError: s1 is not defined`, and if I substitute some value for the four variables, your code runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The `totalDistance` variable only exists inside your `getDistance` function; you cannot see it from outside (this is known as the variable's scope).

Instead, return a value from the function like so:

```
def get_distance(s1, a1, s2, a2):
    streets = abs(s2 - s1) * 500
    avenues = abs(a2 - a1) * 500
    return streets + avenues      # function has to return the result

total_distance = get_distance(s1, a1, s2, a2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any variable inside a function is considered a local variable, which means it cannot be accessed from outside the function. Instead, you can:

```
return totalDistance
```

or:

```
return streets + avenues
```

You could also try unindenting:

```
totalDistance = streets + avenues
```

Because it may be because it is inside the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to return the distance that it calculated, eg,

```
return totalDistance
```

Be careful with the indentation on the last expression as well.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that `s1 is not defined`. When I look at your code, I don't see where `s1` is defined (or `s2` or `a1` or `a2` for that matter)

So when you say

```
getDistance(s1, a1, s2, a2)
```

You need to define those variables beforehand, eg:

```
s1 = 0
a1 = 1
s2 = 2
a2 = 3
getDistance(s1, a1, s2, a2)
```